# nginx + spawn-fcgi is serving raw cgi (binary) file content (not executing them)

Tags: nginx, cgi, nagios, spawn-fcgi

I'm stumped trying to figure out why my nginx + spawn-fastcgi is serving the raw binary content instead of executing them and serving the result.

The goal is to configure Nagios Core 4.x using NginX. There are many great blogs on this; but none have shed light on my problem.

I'm currently using CentOS 6.6 NginX v1.0.15, spawn-fcgi v1.6.3, and php (php-fpm) v5.4.30.

The PHP file hosting works great (php-fpm), **it's just the spawn-fcgi content I'm having an issue with which is i charge of serving the /cgi-bin/*.cgi files. Here is my spwn-fcgi environment:

```
cat << _EOF > /etc/sysconfig/spawn-fcgi
OPTIONS="-u apache -g apache -a 127.0.0.1 -p 9001 -C 32 -F 1 -P /var/run/spawn-fcgi.pid -- /usr/bin/php-cgi"
_EOF
```

My NginX configuration:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name monitor.mydomain.com;
   return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
   listen 443;

   # Satisfy allows us to bypass authentication
   # for allowed ip addresses
   satisfy any;
   # Local Traffic only
   allow   192.168.0.0/24;
   allow   127.0.0.0/8;
   # drop rest of the world
   deny    all;

   server_name monitor.mydomain.com;
   root /usr/share/nagios;

   ssl_session_timeout  5m;
   ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
   ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128:AES256:AES:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK';
   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
   ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;

   ssl on;
   ssl_certificate      /etc/pki/tls/certs/mydomain.com.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key  /etc/pki/tls/private/mydomain.com.key;

   index  index.php index.html index.htm;

   access_log  /var/log/nginx/nagios.access.log;
   error_log /var/log/nginx/nagios.error.log;

   # Security
   auth_basic            "Restricted Area";
   auth_basic_user_file  mynagios.htpasswd;

   location ~ \.htaccess {
      deny all;
   }

   location / { 
      if ($uri ~* "\.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)(\?[0-9]+)?$") {
         expires max;
         break;
      }
   }

   error_page  404              /404.html;
   location = /404.html {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
   }

   # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
   #
   error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
   location = /50x.html {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
   }

   # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
   #
   location ~ \.php$ {
      try_files $uri = 404;

      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
      fastcgi_index  index.php;
      fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      include        fastcgi_params;
   }

   #location ~ \.cgi$ {
   location /nagios/cgi-bin/ {
      root   /usr/lib64/nagios/cgi;
      rewrite ^/nagios/cgi-bin/(.*)\.cgi /$1.cgi break;

      fastcgi_param  AUTH_USER $remote_user;
      fastcgi_param  REMOTE_USER $remote_user;
      fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fcgi.sock;
      fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9001;
      include      fastcgi_params;
   }
}
```

The tool in question is running:

```
[root@fserver conf.d]# netstat -pnat | egrep '900(0|1)'
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      9054/php-fpm        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9001              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      28888/php-cgi
```

Again, in a nutshell; this config is 'almost' working very well, but a request like https://monitor.mydomain.com/nagios/cgi-bin/status.cgi servers the content:

```
ELF>... <raw ugly content>
```

It's also worth noting I *was* using SELinux (wrote my own module for Nagios), but have disabled it (all of SELinux) until i can resolved this cgi issue.

Any advice you guys can provide would be fantastic! TIA

Answer (score 1):

I figured the issue out; should anyone have the same problem as I did, it was a result of not using [fcgiwrap](https://github.com/gnosek/fcgiwrap). I just followed the instructions and compiled it.

Using fcgiwrap allowed me to execute the code spawn-fcgi returned instead of displaying the raw data (my problem):

```
cat << _EOF > /etc/sysconfig/spawn-fcgi
OPTIONS="-u apache -g apache -a 127.0.0.1 -p 9001 -f /usr/sbin/fcgiwrap -P /var/run/spawn-fcgi.pid"
_EOF

# Now restart spawn-fcgi
service spawn-fcgi restart
```

Comment: I used fcgiwrap(but no spawn-fcgi) but I got binary response http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34397333/c-cgi-script-response-is-binary-format