# Nginx serving C++ cgi script: response is binary format

Tags: c++, nginx, cgi

I am trying to run C++ CGI script on nginx. I am using FCGIWrap with [script from nginx website](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/fcgiwrap/#manual-install). The program code is like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{

   cout << "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n";
   cout << "<html>\n";
   cout << "<head>\n";
   cout << "<title>Hello World - First CGI Program</title>\n";
   cout << "</head>\n";
   cout << "<body>\n";
   cout << "<h2>Hello World! This is my first CGI program</h2>\n";
   cout << "</body>\n";
   cout << "</html>\n";

   return 0;
}
```

And I compiled with g++ -o start.cgi start.cpp. So when I run ./start.cgi, I got the correct output. But when I use curl localhost/cgi-bin/start.cgi, I got binary output(and actually see cout responses and information like GCC ... So I suspect it is the compiled executable file)

My nginx.conf:

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user root;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /var/www;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location /cgi-bin/*\.cgi {
          gzip off;
          fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.sock;
          include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
          fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/cgi-bin$fastcgi_script_name;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if the cgi is written in C++, this is really not a C++ issue, right?

Comment: Your C++ shouldn't include the `\r` characters. This is solely an nginx config issue - it's presumably not configured to serve executables without extensions.

Comment: @EML, so the problem is with nginx.conf or?